# Run a C program in CentOS7, what should I do if I encounter errno 9 (Bad file descriptor)?

Tags: c, fopen, errno

In the following code, I'm going to open a file and write something.

Because the program is run concurrently on multiple threads, the value **log_fd** after the **fopen** function finishes executing may be **NULL**.

Then, the program crashes and exits.

```
static void __log_prt__(const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{   
    // omitted code ...

    FILE *log_fd = fopen(def_log_file, "a");

    // omitted code ...

    fclose(log_fd);
}
```

This will lead to **errno 9: Bad file descriptor**

I modified the program to loop through the **fopen** function until its return value is no longer NULL, just like the following code:

```
static void __log_prt__(const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{   
    // omitted code ...

    FILE *log_fd = fopen(def_log_file, "a");
    while (log_fd == NULL) {
        log_fd = fopen(def_log_file, "a");
    }

    // omitted code ...

    fclose(log_fd);
}
```

In this way, the program will no longer have crashes caused by **errno 9**.

Now I have a question, is this the right thing to do? Is there a more reasonable way?

Comment: Why not add *proper* error handling? You know that `fopen` can fail and return a null pointer, but the right solution is almost never to just busy-wait until it's possible to open (which may be *never*). Instead fail gracefully, or worst case tell the user and exit the program.

Comment: Why does concurrency imply that fopen may fail?  Just wondering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FILE *log_fd = fopen(def_log_file, "a");
    while (log_fd == NULL) {
        log_fd = fopen(def_log_file, "a");
    }
```

This approach seems very optimistic. From the man page, I counted around 42 different error conditions that could cause `fopen ()` to fail.¹

If `fopen ()` returns `NULL`, there's no guarantee that recalling it will magically fix the conditions that caused it to fail in the first place.

Remember:

- Failure is always an option.
- Fail fast, fail early, and fail often.
- And do not trade safety for *anything.*

[1] — which includes `ENOMEM` (Error No Memory), at which point you should be aborting.

Comment: Thank you, I've added error handling logic in my program that returns NULL for the fopen function.